Male sibling attacks female
I have two cats, male and female, both neutered. They are 20 months old and have always got along really well, grooming each other, sleeping together etc. in the last few weeks, my male cat has started jumping on and acting aggressively towards his sister.  It’s getting worse and I now fear he will really hurt her when I’m not around. She has now started growing at him when he comes close and literally screams when he attacks her. Sometimes she may be playing but other times she’s asleep and he simple starts jumping on her. What can I do?

This question is similar to: Why does one of my cats attack his siblings?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
